# What is the safe way to adding an FTP user through PHP?

Tags: php, security, ftp

There is a form on the website with "FTP username" and "FTP password" for administrators.

How to safely add the FTP user by PHP? Because currently we are connecting to the server via ssh - root - user, that's the worst solution. So for secondary solution we are added a normal user to the sudoers and enabled only a few commands for the user.

```
echo "testuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/mkdir,/bin/rmdir" > /etc/sudoers.d/testuser
```

But what about the `useradd` command? if we allow that too for the normal user, it will not be safe too isn't it?

Comment: Have you considered writing a shell script that's a wrapper around useradd, and allowing testuser to execute that script via sudo? The wrapper could be very restricted compared to calling useradd directly.

Comment: proftpd for example supports SQL databases for user authentication, and I bet many other systems do too. That might be more viable.